# ASP.NET Core- Is there a way to render group of elements each using custom tag-helpers?

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I noticed in my project that all my form fields follow the same pattern. A typical example is:

```
<div class="col-x-x">
  <label asp-for="Property"></label>
  <span message="description">
  <input asp-for="Property" />
  <span asp-validation-for="Property"></span>
</div>
```

I would love to have some way of grouping this code so that i simply pass it the property on the model and it outputs the correct HTML. e.g.:

```
<form-field for="Property" ...>
```

or

```
@Html.StringFormField(...)
```

The issue I am having is that whatever method I try, the html outputted is the original html above, and not the html that is generated from the tag helpers. I have tried both methods and neither have been successful. Additionally I have tried to create a razor function, but all my attempts fail to compile, and I can't make a partial view work as I haven't been able to find a way to get the property information after passing a string to a view.

My latest attempt was using a tag helper, however this had the same issue mentioned previously. The latest version of the code is as follows:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("form-field", Attributes = "for")]
public class FormFieldTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

        var contentBuilder = new HtmlContentBuilder();

        contentBuilder.AppendHtmlLine($"<label asp-for=\"{For}\"></label>");
        contentBuilder.AppendHtmlLine($"<span message=\"description.\"></span>");
        contentBuilder.AppendHtmlLine($"<input asp-for=\"{For}\"/>");
        contentBuilder.AppendHtmlLine($"<span asp-validation-for=\"{For}\"/></span>");

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(contentBuilder);
    }
}
```

There is an issue addressing this ([with no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754809/use-razor-tag-helpers-inside-custom-tag-helper)) which suggested the order of the imports was a potential issue, so my imports are as follows:

```
@addTagHelper Project.Web.Features.Shared.*, Project.Web
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Any solution would be welcome, either for a tag helper or another method.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [IHtmlGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.ihtmlgenerator?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to generate these elements, refer to my below demo code:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("form-field", Attributes = "for")]
public class FormFieldTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _generator;

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public FormFieldTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            writer.Write(@"<div class=""form-group"">");

            var label = _generator.GenerateLabel(
                            ViewContext,
                            For.ModelExplorer,
                            For.Name, null,
                            new { @class = "control-label" });

            label.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);
            writer.Write(@"<span message=""description.""></span>");

            var textArea = _generator.GenerateTextBox(ViewContext,
                                For.ModelExplorer,
                                For.Name,
                                For.Model,
                                null,
                                new { @class = "form-control" });

            textArea.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);

            var validationMsg = _generator.GenerateValidationMessage(
                                    ViewContext,
                                    For.ModelExplorer,
                                    For.Name,
                                    null,
                                    ViewContext.ValidationMessageElement,
                                    new { @class = "text-danger" });

            validationMsg.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);

            writer.Write(@"</div>");

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
 <form-field for="ManagerName"></form-field>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a really good suggestion, however i failed to mention (and have amended the title) that all tag helpers are custom, so to use this method additional html functions would be needed to duplicate the tag helper functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest way to do this without duplicating custom tag helper code with the html generator is by simply creating new instances of the custom tag helpers from within a new tag helper.

e.g.

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)   
{
    output.TagName = "div";
    output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

    //create label tag
    LabelForTagHelper labelTagHelper = new LabelForTagHelper(ValidatorFactory)
    {
        For = this.For,
        IgnoreRequired = this.IgnoreRequired
    };

    TagHelperOutput labelOutput = new TagHelperOutput(
        tagName: tagName,
        attributes: attributes ?? new TagHelperAttributeList(),
        getChildContentAsync: (s, t) =>
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew<TagHelperContent>(() => new DefaultTagHelperContent());
        }
    );

    var labelElement = await labelTagHelper.ProcessAsync(context, labelOutput);

    output.Content.AppendHtml(labelElement );

    //repeat for other tags
}
```